# Function with many parameters - should an array be used?

Tags: php

Most things I've read into have discussed how 'you should never have more than 2 or 3 parameters for a function!'. However, I need several functions that insert large amounts of data into a database. e.g. impression data which would include the current date, user country, user IP, user carrier, device manufacturer, the list goes on, sometimes to 20+ variables.

In this case, there is no way to simplify the function - it is doing a single action, it just needs many parameters. I've come up with 2 solutions to this. The first is to simply include the list of parameters normally. e.g.:

```
function newMethod($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5, $p6, ...) { }
```

The second is what I personally like a lot more, however it nullifies the useful features of some IDEs involving the function signature. This is that second option:

```
public function addObject(
    $vars = array(
        'options' => array(),
        'data' => array(
            'Object_Attribute' => 0, /* Variable comments */
            'Object_Attribute_2' => '' /* Variable comments */
        )
    )
) {}
```

I can document each variable, so that isn't a problem. (other than the previously mentioned signature issue) With this, I can also simply include sql table names as the keys to make the insertion process even simpler. (using implode, array_keys, etc.)

I don't see any downside to this other than individual preference. Of course, I do need to do a few empty()/isset() calls to make sure critical parameters are there, but that also isn't a huge issue, and in most cases would still be done with the first method anyway to make sure there are no null/empty values.

Could anyone enlighten me with the disadvantages (if any) of the latter method? I'm a big fan of associative arrays and feel like they just look better than a list of xx variables. Is there anything wrong with this preference that could cause major issues down the road, or is this purely an issue with whether programmer A finds it more readable than programmer B?

Comment: If you're using PDO, I'd suggest using an array.

Comment: I would rather use array in case like this

Comment: Use multiple parameters if each of them means different. But if you're just inserting pieces of records, all the parameters are actually in the "same" line in the database. You'd better pass an array to the function and merge it with the array containing the default values.